# Negative Binomial Distribution and Expected Value

Tags: probability, statistics

> Suppose that the probability of making a three pointer is $p=35\%$.
>
> (c) Calculate the expected value and variance for the *number of misses* that you have prior to making your third shot.
>
> (d)  Calculate the expected value for the *total number of shot attempts* that you take in order to make three shots.

I understand that this is a negative binomial distribution so the distribution is as follows:

$$\Pr(M=k)=\binom{2+k}{2} p^3 q^k \text{ for } k=0,1,2,3,\ldots\tag{1}$$

where M is number of misses prior to rth success (in this case $r=3$).

To calculate (c), I did the following:

$$E[M]=\cfrac{rq}{p}=\cfrac{3\cdot0.65}{0.35}=5.57\tag{2}$$

$$Var[M]=\cfrac{rq}{p^2}=\cfrac{3\cdot0.65}{0.35^2}=15.92\tag{3}$$

I'm not sure whether I understand the question to part (d).  In a negative binomial distribution, you can have an infinite number of shot attempts to make 3 shots.  For example, you can have the following sequences:

$$
\begin{align}
SSS \\
\{S,S,M\}S \\
\{S, S, M, M \}S \\
\{S, S, M, M, M \}S \\
\vdots\qquad{}
\end{align}
$$

And to calculate the expected value of each case, you just apply equation (2).  I don't really know whether I understand part (d) and how to solve.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: I would read he total number of shot attempts being 3 + number of misses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: in the first case if your $n^{\text{th}}$ shot is the last, you need 'the number of failures', so your random variable $X$ takes values $\{0,1, \ldots \}$, in the second case you count the 'total number of tosses', so your random variable takes values $\{3,4, \ldots \}$. In the first case the expectation is 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k \binom{k+2}{2}p^2 q^k
$$ 
in the second case it is 
$$
\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}k \binom{k-1}{k-3}p^3q^{k-3}
$$

Does this help now?

Comment: No sorry I don't understand your response at all...

Comment: pls see the edit

Comment: Ohhhh.  Thank you sooo much @Alex!!!  Now that makes more sense.  I think though in your first equation though you should have a $p^3$ since there are 3 shots made right?

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Not quite, because you count the number of tosses $before$ the 3rd one, and in this set there are only 2 successes and $k$ failures

Comment: Are you sure?  If I use your equation (1), then that means my part (c) is wrong, and I looked in the book solutions it matches to what I got.  If I use your equation, then $E[X]=2*0.65/0.35$ right?

Comment: perhaps the confusion comes from alternative definition of NB rv: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Alternative_formulations